# Windows phone 8.1 app deployment error :Error-package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

This is what exactly is did:

Installed  windows phone 8.0 SDK.
 Installed windows phone 8.1 SDK(By first installing VS 2013 professional edition and later installing update R2).
After that 8.1 application xap deployment is failing

Unable to deploy xap on windows 8.1 phone using 8.1 deployment tool “Error-package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation”

The phone i am using is 8.1 updated
Can you please let me know if iam missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1), I just ran into same issue. I had tried to install an appx package which was built for Store in Release Mode.

I then realised I was trying to install an ARM build onto the emulator which needs an x86 build to run.

So instead I deployed the ARM Release Mode .appx to a physical device so I could test what I needed to test.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this addresses the issue you had, consider updating your answer to something that directly answers the question. Otherwise, include this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer but an un-explained work around. I've recently started developing against windows phone.   I am working on a Windows 8.1 machine that was previously a Windows 8 machine, previously using VS 2012 to develop against WP 8 and now using VS 2013 to develop for WP 8.1.

At intervals I start to receive the same error as reported by the question, both when deploying our WP 8.1 app to an emulator and when trying to run or debug our WP 8.1 unit tests.  So far it's been resolved each time by restarting VS 2013 (and the emulator).  Restarting the emulator alone has sometimes been sufficient but not always.  I have not checked whether it works against a concrete device.  More significantly I have no idea why deployment breaks or stopping/starting resolves it...

Our application and unit tests are WP 8.1 silver light projects and use SQLite.